# Add a Button to a TableView Cell:

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UI tableView and I am trying to create a button like the one used in the Safari Settings to Clear History:

[image]

The code I have tried doesnt really work and I'm sure there is a better way:

```
        case(2):
           // cell = [[[ButtonLikeCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


            if (indexPath.row == 0) 
            {            
                UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                [button setFrame:cell.bounds]; 
                [button addTarget:self action:@selector(clearButtonClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
                [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [button setTitle:@"Clear Data" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                cell.accessoryView = nil;
                cell.clipsToBounds=YES;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
            }

            break;
    }
}

return(cell);
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A subclass on the tableview cell is overkill for this, basically all you need to do is set the text alignment of the textLabel to center

```
case(2):
        if (indexPath.row == 0) 
        {   
            cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        }
        break;
```

Comment: you are correct! i was under the impression textLabel goes through sizeToFit so changing the alignment wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

no need to use an actual UIButton.

the only difference between does rows and "normal" rows is the position of the label.
subclass UITableViewCell and override `-laysubviews` to center the label and you're done, like so:

```
@interface ButtonLikeCell : UITableViewCell

@end

@implementation ButtonLikeCell

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    self.titleLabel.center = self.center;
}

@end
```

this will reposition the label of the cell and make it look similar to what you're looking for.

Comment: Could you expand a little Hezi?  This is my first few days in IOs

Comment: thats not a button inside a uitableviewcell, its just a uitableviewcell with the textLabel's textAlignment property set to UITextAlignmentCenter

Comment: @Hezi, Ok I tried the subclass, it looks like the way forward but adding it to my UITableView is causing problems...